# Sending current docx/pptx/xlsx, from online Office 365 apps, to website from Office 365 Add-In.

Tags: office365, office-addins, office365-apps, office365api

I was wondering if it was possible to create an add-in which can post the current document (excel,word and powerpoint) to my website so that I can do operations on it.

I want to strictly focus on the online services i.e. Word Online, Excel Online and Powerpoint Online. I took a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj715279.aspx#offapp_GetDoc_CreateJS but it requires me to slice the document up and assemble it on my end.

Is there anyway to compile the document before posting or just post the document itself. Also is there any method to post to website with Excel Online as the previous link only relates to PowerPoint and Word.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can stream your document to your website or api in office add-ins. So you can do some processing on it.

What i recommend, is to build an API to send your document to from the office add-in. implement any logic in your api.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Mostafa, thanks for the reply. I was just wondering how you would "send" your documents to the API in regards to your method. I am unsure what to use e.g. getFileAsync? That's what I'm having a bit of trouble thinking about. If there is any code samples or resources you could link me, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here are some samples on how to upload files in JS to REST API: 1) Upload a file by using the REST API and jQuery https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn769086.aspx

Comment: I took a look at the link you posted and it looks like it applies more to Sharepoint Add-ins. Does the same method work for Office Add-ins? At the moment, I plan to create an add-in which works for Word Online, Excel Online and Powerpoint online which allows me to somehow pass the document along (probably through my API) to my website. Problem is, the only sample I saw which allows me to do this slices the document and requires me to compile and decode on my end. Is there a work around for this?

Comment: The sample i provided is a JS code to upload a file, it does not matter it if a SP add-in or SP add-in.  second part of your question, is a programming question which you choose what is the best approach that works with you.

Comment: Ok, I'll try get something working. Thanks for the help :)